# Can print statement change logic of the algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I am trying to solve the maximum contagious subarray problem where the goal is to find the maximum sum of any possible subsequence of the list. I devised a collapsing algorithm, where it adds up the same signed neighbors first to get a sequence of alternating sign numbers. Next, I defined a collapse function which sums the sequence if the sum is greater than either of the individual numbers.
Here is the weird problem I'm facing. If I exclude the print statement as first line of `def collapse(list)` function, the program throws me an error. The program is as follows

```py
a=[5,4,-1,7,8]
lena,i= len(a)-1,1
while i <= lena:
    if a[i]*a[i-1] >= 0:
        a[i-1]=a[i]+a[i-1]
        a.pop(i)
        i -= 1
        lena=len(a)-1
    i+=1
print(a)
def collapse(list_):
    #print(list_)
    list_copy = list_
    if list_[0] > 0:
        j = 0
    else:
        j = 1
    if len(list_)<=3:
        list_=max(max((i for i in list_)),sum(list_))
    else:
        for i in range(j + 2, len(list_) - 1, 2):
            if (sum(list_[i - 2:i + 1]) >= max(list_[i - 2], list_[i])):
                list_[i - 2] = sum(list_[i - 2:i + 1])
                list_.pop(i)
                list_.pop(i - 1)
                i -= 2
    if list_copy == list_:
        return list_
    else:
        collapse(list_)

print(max(collapse(a)))
```

The error thrown is `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.  However, if I run the same code by uncommenting the print statement in the function definition as` def collapse(list):  print(list)`, it works and prints me the correct solution. But parallelly it still shows the same error. I don't understand how can a simple print statement possibly affect my program flow.

The error is just specific to the list of length 3 because the loop starts and ends at the same value and hence I had to handle a list of length 3 or less separately. Other lists work perfectly fine with this logic.

Can someone tell me what is happening with this problem?
Also if someone can tell about its time complexity and memory usage as compared to other algorithms like a brute force of kadane's algorithm etc, that would be helpful.

Question on Leetcode is : [Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/)

Various other solutions are : [Solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/discuss/1595195/C%2B%2BPython-7-Simple-Solutions-w-Explanation-or-Brute-Force-%2B-DP-%2B-Kadane-%2B-Divide-and-Conquer)

Comment: I still got the error with the print. Don't name your variable `list` that the builtin python keyword for list constructor

Comment: if you go in  `if len(values) <= 3:` then you change from a real LIST to a int (given by max), you can't call `collapse` again on that int

Comment: I renamed list to A and I still get the same error. Also to resolve the calling of collapse on int I just added a list() outside max so it returns a list of single value. And what should end up happening is it'll call collapse and Acopy will be same as A and the function should exit. However, the same error persists. Also commenting and uncommenting print statement changes solution as earlier case.

Comment: You get the error regardless of the print statement but with print statement the function also works and gives the correct answer but without print statement its just the error and no solution. That's what is bugging me. How can a print statement make the problem work? The error is thrown regardless but the program still works and gives absolutely correct answers for all test cases with the print statement. And without it, it just gives error without any solution.